# Ensure that there is space at the sides of columns and between columns

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

How do I create space between the DOM and the column, my text is too close to the DOM side.

```
<template>

    <div>

<md-layout md-row md-md-columns>

        <md-layout md-column = "5" class = "mdcolor"> 
        <p class = "md-display-1"> Connect Soft documents </p>

          <p class = "">Allow documents that feed into each other to provide a consistent, untainted view of what your institution is doing.</p>

      </md-layout>
</md-layout>

 </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add CSS padding: https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/gRjPgB

```
#app{
  padding-left:10px;
}
```